# OperationalError at /admin/app1/coursemodel/ no such column: app1_coursemodel.money

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i tried to add a new field to already existing model and this is being displayed.

```
class CourseModel(models.Model):
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dur  = models.IntegerField()
    fee = models.IntegerField()
    money = models.IntegerField()  --- this is what is added
```

I tried python makemigrations whc=ich is giving the follwing error:
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'money' to coursemodel without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows). Please select a fix:  1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)  2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.

Comment: The error is very clear. It's a prompt. You want to add a new field in DB, which is mandatory for all rows. The prompt is asking if you want to add a default value (like 0). Otherwise it is good practice to define this value in model field.

Answer (score 0):

first delete migration folder related to that model.

after, Simply you can try these 3 commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #This value will generate after makemigrations. It can be either 0001, 0002 or more

python manage.py migrate
```

and see if it solves that error